# Probability measures and stochastically dependent events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $P(B\mid A) > P(B)$ and $P(C\mid B) > P(C)$ can I infer that $P(C\mid A) > P(C)$? My suspicion is yes but I don't see how to prove it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false, as shown by the following counterexample: let $A$ and $C$ be independent events with $P(A) = P(C) = 1/3$, and let $B$ be the event "$A$ or $C$", which has probability $P(B) = 5/9$. Then $P(B \mid A) = 1 > P(B)$ and $P(C \mid B) = P(C)/P(B) > P(C)$, but $P(C \mid A) = 1/3 = P(C)$.

EDIT: An even more concrete example (in the lines of my comment below) is the following: consider the probability space of all possible outcomes of a regular unbiased dice. Let $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{1,2\}$, $C = \{2\}$ (notice that $A$ and $C$ are not independent).

Then $P(B | A ) = 1 > 1/3 = P(B)$, $P(C | B) = 1/2 > 1/6 = P(C)$ but $P(C | A) = 0$.

Comment: Why is $P(B) = \frac{5}{9}$?

Comment: In fact, the hypothesis of independence is not necessary: just pick $A, C$ such that $P(A \text{ or } C) < 1$ and such that $P(C \mid A) \leq P(C)$. Then the event $B$ = $A$ or $C$ will still work.

Comment: $P(B^c) = P(A^c \text{ and } C^c) = (2/3) \cdot (2/3)$. But this is not particularly important, I just wanted to give a concrete example (we just needed $P(B) < 1$).

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck with the basics. Why is $P(A^c \cap C^c) = P(A^c) \cdot P(C^c)$

Comment: I assumed $A$ and $C$ were independent.

Comment: I don't see yet why this implies that the complements are independent also.

Comment: I see. It follows from the fact that if $A$ and $C$ are independent events, then so are $A$ and $C^c$. To prove this, just observe that $ P(A \cap C^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap C) = P(A)(1 - P(C)) = P(A) P(C^c)$.

Comment: Why does the first equality hold? It seems to be basic but I don't really see it. /edit: For uniform probability measures, I have convinced myself by drawing a diagram. That's a useful thing to know.

Comment: The first equality is just the equation $P(A) = P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap C^c)$ written differently.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for teaching me this and thanks for your example above!